# How to create a Python script standalone

Tags: python

I have a script named `main.py` which needs first that other script is executed. This means that at the top of the script I have included the following:

```
execfile('other_script.py')
```

So when using PyInstaller in Linux an error appears saying that it can't find this file. How can I fix this?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, is there some reason you can't simply use an `import` statement?

Comment: To expand on the above, import the script and run what needs to be run,  then do the rest of your logic. Such as from main import *....the rest of your code

Comment: import does not work, as the other script executes something from Matlab and it throws me an error. The answers here also don't work since I don't want others to see the code of the other script.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path to `other_script.py` starting from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need an

```
__init__.py
```

file in the directory containing the other script